# VScode, error al agregar directorio

Tags: php, vscode, symfony4, wampserver

Tengo instalado *Composer*, *WampServer* he creado el proyecto *Symfony 4.4* dentro de la ruta `C:\wamp64\www` pero al intentar agregar la carpeta del proyecto a VSCode me da el siguiente error:

> spawn /usr/bin/php ENOENT

¿A que se debe?

Comment: Creo que ese error quiere decir que vscode no logra acceder al ejecutable de php. Intenta configurar tus extensiones para que usen el ejecutable de php que viene incluido en wampserver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola el error tiene poco que ver con el servidor o con composer; el error radica en que debes tener la extensión de Symfony instalada y su ruta predeterminada para php.exe es /usr/bin/php.

Cámbielo agregando esta línea en settings.json:

```
"symfony-vscode.phpExecutablePath": "%%Path%%\\php.exe"
```

Toma en cuenta que tu %%Path%% debes remplazarlo con algo similar a:

```
C:\\xampp\\php
```

Esta descrito en:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55490761/4717133

Para Git:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42547408/4717133

y en la sección de VSCode:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/27688804/4717133